# cannot source workspace

Tags: ros, catkin, permissions, ros-indigo, catkin-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to source my workspace. I copied the workspace of a external drive. When I try to source it t I get the following error. I am running indigo on 14.04.

```
nathaniel@nathaniel:~/Documents/Omnibot/code/catkin_ws$ source devel/setup.bash bash: /home/nathaniel/Documents/Omnibot/code/catkin_ws/devel/_setup_util.py: Permission denied
Failed to run '"/home/nathaniel/Documents/Omnibot/code/catkin_ws/devel/_setup_util.py" ': return code 126
nathaniel@nathaniel:~/Documents/Omnibot/code/catkin_ws$
```

How can I fix this workspace? I do not want to copy all the files in to another workspace.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229038/cannot-source-workspace/) by [ngoldfarb](https://answers.ros.org/users/23280/ngoldfarb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 127 on 2016-03-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-03-14**:
Probably some file paths are not correct anymore. Have you tried removing `build` and  `devel` and do another `catkin_make` before sourcing it on the new machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you copied the files from an external drive that was formatted for windows, the execute permissions on your files were probably lost.

It's also possible that your files are owned by the wrong user, but this is unlikely.

You could fix this by going through each file and fixing the permissions by restoring read and/or execute permission where necessary.

The less labor-intensive and safer way to fix this is by rebuilding the workspace, if you can. Just delete the build and devel folders, and run catkin_make to rebuild the workspace. This has the additional benefit of making sure that all of your executables will be recompiled for the new machine, since it might have slightly different versions of packages.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ngoldfarb](https://answers.ros.org/users/23280/ngoldfarb/) on 2016-03-14**:
I did that and got this as an output

```
The specified base path "/home/nathaniel/Documents/Omnibot/code/catkin_ws" contains a CMakeLists.txt but "catkin_make" must be invoked in the root of workspace
```

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-03-14**:
catkin_make doesn't like a CMakeLists.txt in the current directory; it expects all of your source code to be in the `src` directory. Are you sure you copied your workspace correctly?

**Comment by [ngoldfarb](https://answers.ros.org/users/23280/ngoldfarb/) on 2016-03-14**:
All my code is in my src dir. I just copied and pasted it. It was created on another computer.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-03-14**:
catkin_make says there's a CMakeLists.txt in your catkin_ws directory. you should figure out why it's there and move it somewhere else or remove it; then try to run catkin_make again.